# Cant pass PWA lighthouse test despite service worker being installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've been currently working on PWA and I've run into a problem. Despite having my service worker installed and caching files, my app receives all of the lighthouse PWA marks except one for being installable. I have no idea what's wrong, so I hope someone has some idea.

You can find my app at https://endearing-mooncake-1d9a8d.netlify.app/logIn but it is meant to be used on <750px screens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not resolving properly for an icon. You can see in the console window that it has this challenge.  Research on your page that location relative to this page and determine if this is a real actual PNG file or if the path is somehow incorrect.

> logIn:1 Error while trying to use the following icon from the
> Manifest:
> https://endearing-mooncake-1d9a8d.netlify.app/src/assets/maskable_icon.png
> (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I've moved logo and maskable_icon to public folder and change their src in manifest to:

    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "logo.png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        },
        {
            "src": "maskable_icon.png",
            "sizes": "307x307",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any maskable"
        }
    ],

But this doesnt seem to fix the issue. Also where do you find this error? I can find it anywhere

Comment: Open your chrome browser, hit F12 and click `console` to see the error

Comment: Yeah but my console is clear except for service worker log "Success: https://endearing-mooncake-1d9a8d.netlify.app/" screen shot -> https://i.imgur.com/Sb0GX3h.png

Comment: Hit F12, run the Lighthouse "Analyze page load", then it will show the PWA (which at this point appears to be corrected) previously it showed that error.  Good job fixing it!

Comment: So it was really this png - thanks a lot ! <3